# Using a object specific variable in another class

Tags: java, oop, object, instance, non-static

I've been looking across all the other questions but i cant seem to find an answer to my problem: I need to use a non-static field (which is separate for each object i create) and I need to access that variable in another class. Piece of the code: (Enemytank.java)

```
public class Enemytank extends MoveableGameItem implements IStepListener, IAlarmListener
{
    private Battlefield mygame;

    private Enemytank enemyTank1;   
    private static int enemyWaveSize = 1;
    private static int remainingKills = enemyWaveSize;
    private static double startupEnemyHealth = 100.00;
    private double enemyHealth = startupEnemyHealth;
    public int enemyStage = 0;              


    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public Enemytank(Battlefield mg)
    {
        mygame = mg;
        setImage("/images/enemytank.png", 27, 33);
        setPosition(25, 35);
        // snelheid 5, naar rechts
        setDirectionSpeed(0, 4);
        startMoving();
        mygame.addStepListener(this);
    }
}
```

And the class in which i need the variable *enemyStage*: (Playertank.java)

```
public void collisionOccured(GameItem collidedItem)
    {
        Enemytank enemyTank1 = new Enemytank(mygame);
        System.out.println("pt= " + enemyTank1.getEnemyStage());
        if ((collidedItem instanceof Enemytank) && (playerShields > 0) && (enemyTank1.getEnemyStage() != 3))
        {
            this.playerShields--;
            mygame.setShieldsonDashboard(playerShields);

        }
        else if ((collidedItem instanceof Enemytank) && (playerShields <= 0) && (enemyTank1.getEnemyStage() != 3))
        {
            System.out.println("hit player!");
            this.playerLives--;
            mygame.setLivesonDashboard(playerLives);
        }
        if (collidedItem instanceof Shield)
        {
            this.playerShields++;
            mygame.setShieldsonDashboard(playerShields);
            mygame.deleteGameItem(collidedItem);
            this.playerUpgrades();
        }
    }
```

The value I now get from enemyTank1.getEnemyStage() is 0, because i believe i make a new object with *Enemytank enemyTank1 = new Enemytank(mygame);*. How can I refer to the existing object, and get that specific value? enemyStage is used to check if the monster is dead or almost dead.

Thx in advance :)
Flame

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I refer to the existing object, and get that specific value?". What is the existing object you are interested? You may want to show more of the code. How and where is the enemyStage getting set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to leverage polymorphism. Declare the method `getEnemyStage` in the `GameItem` class (or is it interface?) and then you'll be able to ask `collidedItem.getEnemyStage()` and get the data from exactly that object. Alternatively, *downcast* the `collidedItem` into `EnemyTank` and call the method: `((EnemyTank)collidedItem).getEnemyStage()`

Also, make `enemyStage` `private`, no need to be `public` as it will be accessed indirectly, by calling the getter method.

```
if (collidedItem instanceof Enemytank && playerShields > 0 && 
    ((Enemytank)collidedItem).getEnemyStage() != 3) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: -MoveableGameItem.java is an abstract class which extends GameItem
-GameItem.java is an abstract class

Comment: also, GameItem.java extends to nothing. I can't do the getEnemyStage() in there because it doesnt see anything of Enemytank.java right? I tried extending battlefield.Enemytank (its in another package) but it says some superconstructor is undefined

Comment: Try the code in the updated answer. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: update: thanks! I downcasted it and it seems to be working now :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, is your answer using polymorphism, especially declaring the method in the `GameItem` class also usable even if that class is in another package? Because I am struggling with that right now. Cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a refrence to the object when you call collisionOccured. so, change collisionOccured to this:

```
public void collisionOccured(GameItem collidedItem, Enemytank enemyTank) //a change here
    {
        System.out.println("pt= " + enemyTank.getEnemyStage()); // now you can call enemyTank with the correct refrence
        if ((collidedItem instanceof Enemytank) && (playerShields > 0) && (enemyTank1.getEnemyStage() != 3))
        {
            this.playerShields--;
            mygame.setShieldsonDashboard(playerShields);

        }
        else if ((collidedItem instanceof Enemytank) && (playerShields <= 0) && (enemyTank.getEnemyStage() != 3))
        {
            System.out.println("hit player!");
            this.playerLives--;
            mygame.setLivesonDashboard(playerLives);
        }
        if (collidedItem instanceof Shield)
        {
            this.playerShields++;
            mygame.setShieldsonDashboard(playerShields);
            mygame.deleteGameItem(collidedItem);
            this.playerUpgrades();
        }
    }
```

And, when you call collisionOccured from within EnemyTank class you like this:

```
collisionOccured(collidedItem, this); //where this refrence to this object (which is a EnemyTank)
```

With this answer, I assume that you call collisonOccured from within the EnemyTank class as you did not post where that call is beeing made. If not, you need a refrence to a object of EnemyTank when you call collisionOccured (and therefore change `this` in the call to refrence to the correct object)

Comment: i cant do this since the method collisionOccured is in MoveableGameItem.java which extends to GameItem.java. I cant point towards 'Enemytank enemyTank'